# PYTHON : Saving multiple images into folder using requests

Tags: python-requests

I need to save all 6 images into a local folder.

The script I found re-writes a single files multiple times and end up producing only 1 image

````
import requests

img_list = ["https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1tT70vhuTBuNkHFNRq6A9qpXa3.jpg", "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB12HGkvwKTBuNkSne1q6yJoXXaR.jpg", "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1_yDic56guuRjy0Fmq6y0DXXaY.jpg", "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1RopgXffsK1RjSszgq6yXzpXa5.jpg", "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1R6sJXgHqK1RjSZFkq6x.WFXaF.jpg", "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1_XlhXojrK1RkHFNRq6ySvpXaR.jpg"]
for x in blob:
    with open('/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/wholesale/img/pic1.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
        response = requests.get(x, stream=True)

        if not response.ok:
            print(response)

        for block in response.iter_content(1024):
            if not block:
                break

            handle.write(block)```


It needs to save all 6 images separately. No error message so far.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script rewrites the same file each time because you're using the same file name, it never changes.

The problem is here:

```py
with open('/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/wholesale/img/pic1.jpg', 'wb')
```

The first argument of the `open()` method is the file path. The second argument is the mode, which you have set to `wb`, or write/binary. So in you're loop you are rewriting the file contents of `pic1.jpg` everytime. (See: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open).

You can pre-define a list of filenames in a list and use those as the filenames or do something more dynamic like :

```py
for img in img_list:
    file_name = img.split('/')[-1]
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as handle:
        ....
```

This would grab the file name of the image from the website you're downloading it from (e.g., `1HTB1tT70vhuTBuNkHFNRq6A9qpXa3.jpg` for the first URL) to be used as the file name on your system. (Note: this also assumes names will be unique).

**Edit**:

You can define your folder path before the for-loop. Then, you can change the `open()` method to include that path. So:

```py
import os # do this at the top of your file

folder_path = '/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/wholesale/img/'

for img in img_list:
    with open(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name), 'wb') as handle:
    ....
```

Comment: where should I define the folder path ?

Comment: @Reezal2040 I edited the post. Please accept my answer as the solution if it solves your issue.